# Trouble with C++ maps and their content

Tags: c++, dictionary, output

This is rather extensive, so in advance, if you get through this, even without an answer or solution, thank you.

So, I have this program that is meant to be a basic social network, minus the user-interface, in which a user is represented by a `Person` object, which is responsible for maintaining a friend list, a block list, a list of messages, and a queue of pending friend requests. These lists are, respectively, of types `std::map<std::string, Person>`, `std::map<std::string, Person>`, `std::vector<Message>`, and `std::queue<Message>`, where the `std::string` for the two maps is a concatenation of the user's first and last names and the `Message` in the final two containers are and additional class I have defined. I have overloaded the `<<` operator for `Person` such that it prints the user's first and last names, with a space in between. For some reason, when I go to print these names out, the return is empty, and I have no idea why. The following code is essentially a walkthrough what is happening.

The lines I am using to test my code in the main class:

```
std::string cFirst ("Chris");
std::string cLast ("Cringle");
SocialNetwork sn;
sn.addUser(cFirst,cLast);
```

The `addUser()` function in `SocialNetwork`:

```
void SocialNetwork::addUser(std::string first, std::string last){
std::string name = (first + last);
Person user (first, last);
_users.insert(std::pair<std::string, Person>(name, user));
}
```

Where `_users` is member data on the `SocialNetwork` of type `std::map<std::string, Person>`. The constructor for `Person` is:

```
Person::Person(std::string first, std::string last){
_first = first;
_last = last;
}
```

Where `_first` and `_last` are member data on `Person` that represent the user's first and last names. Then, back in the main class, after `sn.addUser(cFirst,cLast);`:

```
sn.printUsers();
```

Which looks like:

```
void SocialNetwork::printUsers(){
std::map<std::string, Person>::iterator it;
it = _users.begin();
while(it != _users.end()){
    cout << it->first << endl;
    cout << it->second << endl;
    it++;
    }
}
```

With the given code I have, the expected output for `cout << it->first << endl;` should be `ChrisCringle`, and it is. The expected output for `cout << it->second << endl;` should call the overloaded operator and should be `Chris Cringle`, but it simply prints a blank space. Any indications as to why would be greatly appreciated. Do I need to pass my params by reference? I have tried this already and seem to run into a lot of trouble. If something appears to be missing that may help, feel free to ask! Thanks again! I know I'll probably get a lot of flak for this long question but I do not think I can manage to make this any more of a simple question.

EDIT: The code for the overloaded operator is:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& per){
os << per._first << " " << per._last;
return os;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a social network contain a `std::map<Person, std::vector<Person> >`? A **person** has a **friend's**  *list*.

Comment: It'd be cool to see some self-contained peace of code that one can run

Comment: @erip I am using the concatenated name as the key to search for them. Also, if I'm not mistaken, your solution only allows for a friend's list, correct? And not the remaining lists?

Comment: Could you show the code for how you implemented overloading the operator? Also are the std::vector<Message>/std::queue<Message> relevant to this problem? (I am not seeing that they come in anywhere, but as you took the time to tell about them I wanted to confirm this.) Are you able to try and design a minimalist implementation of the code that can be tested?

Comment: I know what you're doing. What I'm saying is it is not a great design.

Comment: @RiaD Do you mean you would like me to post some code that you may work with, and if so, what exactly would you need?

Comment: @erip I figured as much, but at this point in the game, this is what I have to work with. Sorry!

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ChrisBritt The overloaded operator has been added, sorry about that. Regarding the vector and queue, I don't suppose they are actually relevant, perhaps I should remove them...

Comment: @AnonMail Will do, just give me one moment.

Comment: `Person` cannot contain `std::map<std::string, Person>`  (standard containers must be instantiated with complete types).  But even if it could, this data structure could not possibly maintain a friend network.

Comment: Remember that containers store objects by value. Probably you're mistakenly assuming somewhere that your objects have reference semantics (like they do in C# or Java). But in C++ each assignment makes a complete copy of the object.

Comment: @M.M What do you mean "complete type"? Are you saying that `Person` is not complete and therefore cannot be used in the map?

Comment: @CreasyBear yes, a class type is not complete until the `}` is reached at the end of its definition

Comment: @M.M So I should pass by reference or pointer or something of the kind? This usually causes a lot of trouble for me...

Comment: If you want to *refer to* other `Person` objects then you must use reference semantics.  Broadly speaking there are two options: use smart-pointers (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`), or represent your links in other ways, e.g. a list of unique keys.

Comment: @M.M I just realized that I will not need to have map for the friend's list anyway, as I can just search by name.

Comment: @CreasyBear yes that would fall under "list of unique keys". So (using RiaD's code as a base), all the `Person`s only occur in one place: `_users` in the singleton SocialNetwork object.  Then any other code that mentions a person uses their name (or perhaps an integer, if you want to allow users to change their names) and you have a function in SocialNetwork that looks up the user list based on that name or integer.

Comment: @M.M What type of container would you recommend if I were to create a friend's list that contained unique values and that could easily be searched for a given value? In other words, what is the best way to store and search for unique values?

Comment: I'd use something like `typedef unsigned long PersonUniqueID; map<PersonUniqueID, Person> users;`   . The map is well suited to searching by key.  In terms of scalability, if you were actually going to have millions of users you'd have to switch to using a database instead of in-memory structures, but for now you can use a map :)

Comment: @M.M But I was under the impression that a map is a key:value relationship. If the key was the name and that is all I need, what would the value be? or would I even need a value?

Comment: @CreasyBear What if there are two or more people named "John Smith" (a very common name).  How would your design work?  Maybe you should be using a `std::multimap` instead of `std::map`?  Also, you didn't check if `map::insert` returned a success code (it returns a `std::pair`, an iterator and `bool`).  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Comment: The value is a `Person` object; in RiaD's example that only contains their name but presumably you'll end up with other info (date of birth, photo , list of friends' IDs). This is where all your people are stored in memory.   Using a number instead of a name as the key lets the person change their name.

Comment: @M.M Oh, I see what you mean. This would apply to the list of users in the `SocialNetwork`. What I was referring to was the list of friends contained in each `Person` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used all the code you've shown: http://ideone.com/mFBxTC

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    Person(std::string first, std::string last);
    std::string _first, _last;
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& per){
    os << per._first << " " << per._last;
    return os;
}


struct SocialNetwork {
    void addUser(std::string first, std::string last);
    std::map<std::string, Person> _users;
    void printUsers();
};


void SocialNetwork::addUser(std::string first, std::string last){
  std::string name = (first + last);
  Person user (first, last);
  _users.insert(std::pair<std::string, Person>(name, user));
}

Person::Person(std::string first, std::string last){
  _first = first;
  _last = last;
}

void SocialNetwork::printUsers(){
std::map<std::string, Person>::iterator it;
it = _users.begin();
while(it != _users.end()){
        cout << it->first << endl;
        cout << it->second << endl;
        it++;
    }
}


int main() {
    std::string cFirst ("Chris");
    std::string cLast ("Cringle");
    SocialNetwork sn;
    sn.addUser(cFirst,cLast);
    sn.printUsers();
    return 0;
}
```

And it works fine. So error is elsewhere

Thats why one should post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when posting debugging questions.

Comment: This network doesn't have any links between users (i.e. who is friends with who), which is where OP's difficulties seem to be starting

Comment: @M.M It don't really see that from the question, OP says "I am using to test my code in the main class: [and then code i  main]". But surely that may be true:)

Comment: You might be right, hard to say without a MCVE. I interpreted his second paragraph to mean that `Person` contains `map<string, Person>` representing that person's friends.

Comment: @M.M This interpretation is correct, and I am not sure exactly what to include in the MCVE now, seeing as this code which I have posted is actually outputting correctly as RiaD has shown. I have tested this code in a separate program and it functions as intended, so my missing output must be caused by something else...

Comment: @RiaD Yes, I greatly apologize for the lack of complete code, but I have been looking at this for a while and came to the conclusion that this code must have been responsible for the incorrect output, but clearly I have missed something.

Comment: @RiaD I've noticed that the design you use does not explicitly make `_first` and `_last` private. Does C++ by default make them private, or could that be the reason I am having trouble?

Comment: They are public here because Person is struct (not a class). If they were private it wouldn't compile because of non-friend free operator<<. You may make it friend and make fields private if you want